# Buscar valores en matriz 2D

Tags: c++, array

> Dado un valor `N` y otro `R` (ambos menores a 50), una matriz `MAT[N][R]` que contiene valores enteros positivos, informe la ubicación del primer cero de cada fila o un cartel indicando si no lo hay.

---

He intentado el siguiente código en C++:

```c++
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int N = 0, R = 0;

    cout << "Ingrese N: ";
    cin >> N;
    cout << "Ingrese R: ";
    cin >> R;

    if (N < 50 && R < 50) {
        int MAT[N][R] = {0};

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < R; j++) {
                cout << "Ingrese el valor de la fila " << i << " columna " << j << ": ";
                cin >> MAT[i][j];

                if (MAT[i][j] < 0) {
                    MAT[i][j] *= -1;
                }
            }
        }

        bool encontrado;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < R; j++) {
                if (MAT[i][j] == 0) {
                    cout << "El primer cero de la fila " << i << " se encontro en la posicion " << j << endl;
                    encontrado = true;
                    i = R;
                }
            }
            if (!encontrado) {
                cout << "No hay ceros en la fila " << i << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Pero ante la entrada de por ejemplo `N=2`, `R=2` y la matriz nula (todos sus elementos son `0`) no genera la salida esperada:

[image: Ejemplo]

La última línea debería decir:

> El primer cero de la fila **1** se encontro en la posicion 1

¿Cómo se podría arreglar el código?

P.D. No se permite el uso de funciones que resuelvan directamente el problema.

Answer (score 2):

#### Uso incorrecto del tamaño de la matriz.

Las dimensiones de una formación<sup>1</sup> bidimensional deben ser conocidas en tiempo de compilación<sup>2</sup>. Es decir: no pueden ser variables. Definir una formación con variables es una característica que se conoce como Formación de Tamaño Variable (FTV) y no es C++ estándar. Lee [estos hilos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=vla) para saber más detalles.

#### Problema.

No restableces la bandera de control en la búsqueda de ceros:

```
bool encontrado;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < R; j++) {
        if (MAT[i][j] == 0) {
            cout << "El primer cero de la fila " << i << " se encontro en la posicion " << j << endl;
            encontrado = true; // <--- Encontrado!
            i = R;
        }
    }
    if (!encontrado) {
        cout << "No hay ceros en la fila " << i << endl;
    }
    // Finaliza el bucle, empieza un nuevo ciclo, restablecemos la bandera
    encontrado = false;
}
```

Además, tu bandera empieza con un valor indeterminado, que podría afectar al resultado de la ejecución hasta que se encuentre el primer cero.

#### Propuesta.

Estás programando en C++, así que saca provecho de las herramientas que el lenguaje ofrece. Empieza por usar un contenedor de datos para tu matriz (como [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)), puedes hacer unos alias de tipos para facilitar la tarea:

```
using fila = std::vector<int>;
using matriz = std::vector<fila>;
```

Usa unos nombres autoexplicativos para tus variables, hará que el código sea más legible, fácil de entender y fácil de mantener:

```
int Filas = 0, Columnas = 0;

cout << "Ingrese Filas: ";
cin >> Filas;
cout << "Ingrese Columnas: ";
cin >> Columnas;

if (Filas < 50 && Columnas < 50) {
    matriz MAT(Filas, fila(Columnas));
```

Usando el `for` de rango, escribirás menos código:

```
int índice = 0;

for (auto &f : MAT) {
    for (auto &v : f) {
        cout << "Ingrese el valor de la fila " << (indice / Columnas) << " columna " << (indice % Columnas) << ": ";
        cin >> v;

        if (v < 0) {
            v *= -1;
        }
        ++indice;
    }
}
```

Puedes ver la propuesta funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bSmtzRb2zGL6BrGD).

---

1. También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.
2. A no ser que se cree con `new`.

Comment: ¡Gracias por la explicación! (1) Con respecto a que el array debe ser conocido en tiempo de compilación, ¿es un problema que debe solventarse sí o sí, o es un problema secundario? (2) No tengo permitido el uso de la línea `#include <vector>` ni cosas como `<int>`, `<fila>` ni `&`. Estamos iniciando en la programación en C++.

Comment: 1) El código que muestras implica que el tamaño del array debe ser conocido en tiempo de EJECUCIÓN, ya que estás pidiendo el tamaño en ejecución, no estableciéndolo como constante. 2) `<vector>`, los alias como `fila` y las referencias (`&`) son C++ puro y son herramientas pensadas para que enseñar y aprender C++ sea más fácil, es absurdo y contraproducente no usarlas.